# Oracle SQL - JOIN table on itself, ON (column * -1)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table `A` like

```
ID NAME AMOUNT, AGE, COMMENT
1  Fred  10     11   likes ice cream
2  Joe   20     12   hates ice cream
3  Mike  -10    44   missing
```

I'd like to have the result set by inner joining on itself on A.AMOUNT equal to -1 * B.AMOUNT:

```
ID NAME AMOUNT, AGE, COMMENT          B.AMOUNT    B.COMMENT2
1  Fred  10     11   likes ice cream   -10         missing
```

I've tried `A.AMOUNT = -B.AMOUNT, 
A.AMOUNT = -1*B.AMOUNT, 
CONCAT('-',B.AMOUNT) = A.AMOUNT`

But none of them seem to work. With `CONCAT`, I get `ORA-01722: invalid number`

Comment: `JOIN B ON B.AMOUNT = 0 - A.AMOUNT`?

Comment: `join ... on A.AMOUNT = -B.AMOUNT` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `amount` is of a numeric datatype, you can just do:

```
select 
    a.*,
    b.amount,
    b.comment
from mytable a
inner join mytable b on a.amount = -1 * b.amount
where a.amount > 0
```

Note: as commented by a_horse_with_no_name, the join condition can be simplified as:

```
a.amount = -b.amount
```

Comment: You can simplify `-1 * b.amount` to `-b.amount`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try this:

```
select 
    a.*,
    b.amount,
    b.comment
from mytable a
inner join mytable b on a.amount + b.amount = 0
where a.amount > 0
```

Other method of doing the same is

```
select 
    a.*,
    b.amount,
    b.comment
from mytable a
inner join mytable b on a.amount = 0 - b.amount
where a.amount > 0
```

Cheers!!